# Xampp - PHP - SQLDatabase

Tags: php, html, xampp

I need to search the data from database.

```
<?php

       if(isset($_POST['Search']))
        {
          $id = $_POST['id'];
          $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
          $query = "SELECT `id`, `FName`, `LName` FROM `testtable'  WHERE 'id' = $id LIMIT 1";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
            $FName = $row['FName'];
            $LName = $row['LName']; 
          }
            else 
              {
                  echo "Undefined ID";
                  $FName = "";
                  $LName = "";
              }

                 mysqli_free_result($result);
                 mysqli_close($connect);
              }

               else{

                    $FName = "";
                    $LName = "";
                   }

       ?>
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
          <title> PHP </title>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          </head>
          <form action="php_search_in_mysql_database.php" method="post">
          id:<input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
          FName:<input type="text" name="FName" value="<?php echo $FName;?>">                <br><br>
          LName:<input type="text" name="LName" value="<?php echo $LName;?>"><br><br>
         <input type="Submit" name="Search" value="Search">
    </form>
     </html>
```

In my php program if I press search button I got an error like below

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.35

It is in htdocs folder only
 I checked with the spellings also.
 I hope the program is correct.

But I am getting the error like above.

I have a doubt in line  - form action = php_search_in_mysql_database.php

Is this correct ?

I am new to php and sql. Kindly help me to run this progarm.

Comment: You might need to provide more info

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the page that you want to open doesnt exist make sure that the page or the folder that you wanna access exists on the htdocs thnxx

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked that is in htdocs folder only